# How can I compare items in list whether their reverse exist or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

can anyone help me with the code for following question:

Write a program that does the following:
Accept the following inputs:
(1) Number of nodes
(2) A 2-D array representing edges. ith edge connects node input2[0][i] to node input2[1][i].
Assuming that a line can be drawn between nodes if there is an edge between them, print number of lines that can be drawn between nodes.

```
Sample test case:1
input1: 4
input2: {{1,1,1},{2,3,4}}
output1: 3
```

**So what I've done so far is:**
I compared items in list which are not equal & that is working fine
but i wanna avoid comparison of elements like 1--2 and 2--1 because they'll be considered as same
& that needs to be ignored.......i tried so much but i couldnt figure out any possible way

PS: I'm talking about the input case like:
input2: {{1,2,3} , {2,3,1}}
Then lines/edges can be drawn are (1,2), (1,3), (2,3) & points like (2,1) and (3,2) will be avoided because they already exist, so my question is HOW can I ignore checking where edges already have been created?

Comment: What do you mean be ith here? : ith edge connects node input2[0][i] to node input2[1][i].

Comment: ith is like an iterator i guess, to iterate items in 2D array

Comment: Wouldnt the lines be the length of the edges lists?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. 
But lines that can be drawn in given input case will be (1,2) ; (1,3) ; (1,4)

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to compare each element in one list with the element _in the same position_ in the second list, so I don't see how could you have repeated comparisons. But anyhow you should post your code if you want a better answer

Comment: More or less that the answer is `function lines (nodes, edges): return len(edges[0])` unless lines(4, ({1, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 4, 1})  still needs to return 3  (as there's an edges from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1)

Comment: Exactly, so that's what I'm asking how can I implement that

Comment: I would zip up the edge pairs but sort them and count the uniques

Comment: Damn you're genius...thanks for your help bro
I was trying to use list and comparing items through for loop but that didnt work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something likes this, maybe:

```
>>> def lines(nodes, edges):
...     return len(set((a, b) if a >= b else (b, a) for a, b in zip(*edges)))
... 
>>> lines(4, ((1, 1, 1), (2, 3, 4)))
3
>>> lines(4, ((1, 1, 1, 2), (2, 3, 4, 1)))
3
>>>
```

Comment: This worked. Mind explaining me what did you do in the return statement exactly?

Comment: Zip up the edges (zip(*edges)), sort the nodes (a, b if a < b else b, a), removes duplicates (set) and counts the unique node pairs (len)